# TinyGet and stress testing

Tags: asp.net, debugging, stress-testing

I am trying to use TinyGet t stress test an application.  I am running the following command:

"C:\Program Files\IIS Resources\TinyGet\tinyget.exe" -srv:localhost -uri:/testwebsite/default.aspx -loop:10

It appears to work as there is no error message.  However, the ASP.NET process does not appear.  Should the ASP.NET process appear?

Is there any documentation for TinyGet.

**Update 17/07/2012**
Is anyone able to confirm that the thread flag (http://code.google.com/p/toolsdotnet/wiki/TinyGet) is referring to the number of worker threads, IO threads or both?

Comment: Have you read this **http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the IIS toolkit on a Windows XP PC with IIS 5.1 (development PC).  I have now installed it on a Windows 2003 server and it works as expected.