# TinyGet and Session Variables

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis-6, stress-testing

I am using TinyGet to stress test a website and monitor the W3WC process memory.  The command I am using is as follows:

"C:\Program Files\IIS Resources\TinyGet\tinyget.exe" -a:ntlm -m:domainname -u:TestUser -p:TestPassword -srv:localhost -uri:/TestWebsite/TestWebPage.aspx -threads:2 -loop:10

This command works.  However, TestWebPage.aspx is passed session variables from the previous page.  Is there a way to simulate session variables in TinyGet?

Comment: Is this question related to this?? **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522559/tinyget-and-stress-testing**

Comment: @ huMpty duMpty, the first question asks why the W3WC process does not appear when I run TinyGet. I have answered this question (for future users). This question asks how to simulate session variables in TinyGet. The questions are not related.